# Interceptor's @AroundInvoke not triggered

Tags: java, aop, interceptor

I'm studying how interceptors works in java. I'm using Netbeans IDE and just created a new project called Interceptors.

I created an annotation called "logged"

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface Logged { }
```

Then I created a class "LoggedInterceptor"

```
@Interceptor
public class LoggedInterceptor implements Serializable {

    public LoggedInterceptor() {}

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object logMethodEntry(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception 
    {

        System.out.println("Entering method: "
                + invocationContext.getMethod().getName() + " in class "
                + invocationContext.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getName());

        return invocationContext.proceed();
    }
}
```

Then I just created a class that make use of Logged annotation

```
public class SuperService 
{
    @Logged
    public String deliverService(String uid) 
    {
        return uid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SuperService ss = new SuperService();
        System.out.println(ss.deliverService("sisi"));
    }
}
```

Nothing happened. Later I added under src/main/resources/META-INF/ an xml file called beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <interceptors>
        <class>ascompany.interceptors.LoggedInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

But logMethodEntry method doesn't get called when I call deliverService method. Am I missing some other configuration file? Or just something else?

I already tried to add @Priority annotation to LoggedInterceptor but nothing changed...

EDIT:

I added logget annotation to LoggedInterceptor as @Luciano van der Veekens  said but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to annotate the LoggedInterceptor class with `@Logged`. This actually binds the annotation to the interceptor.

```
@Logged
@Interceptor
public class LoggedInterceptor implements Serializable {
}
```

They do the same in one of the [Java EE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhpa.html#gkhrq) tutorials.

Also it looks like `SuperService` is just a regular class. An interceptor is a Java EE concept and only works for EJBs deployed on an application server.

Comment: I added it...but nothing changed...something else?

Comment: @MarcoCastano interceptors only works on EJBs deployed on an application server

Comment: @LucianVanDerVeekens ok so I thinked it wrong...thanks for your time...you know if there is something that can be executed before or after a method execution in this way?